# descifrando un código que fue encriptado con OTP y codificado con Latin-1

Tags: python, python-3.x, encriptación

**Yo tengo problemas entendiendo el siguiente enunciado:**

Fue capturado un texto cifrado que fue encriptado usando el OTP, el cual está codicado en latin-1 y
se muestra en hexadecimal. Se sabe que fue escrito en español e incluye espacios, puntos, y demás signos
de puntuación. Este fue encriptado utilizando una llave de 128 bits. Su misión es desencriptar el texto.

f4c4e842d8d77c7323770fa3520a954bd385e859c085d726267c4c9a4148885196e6fa45cdc0f17f677700...

No sé por donde empezar para descifrar este código, primero tengo que pasar todo a bits para poder utilizar XOR? O qué es lo primero que tengo que hacer, muchas gracias!

Comment: Entiendo que la OTP es una secuencia aleatoria de 128 bits y que se trata de descubrir cuál esa secuencia para obtener un texto "con sentido"? Si no hay más pistas me parece prácticamente imposible de resolver. Con 128 bits pueden existir 2**128 claves posibles. No veo cómo reducir el espacio de búsqueda, ya que en latin1 cualquier byte es un valor válido (sería más fácil si fuese utf8, y aún así...) Al decir que está escrito en español ¿se entiende que es ASCII puro, o puede contener acentos y eñes? Entiendo lo segundo, pues de lo contrario latin1 sería irrelevante...

Comment: Fuerza bruta es impracticable en este caso. Aún siendo capaces a probar mil millones de claves por segundo, el tiempo esperado para dar con la respuesta sería más de 391 billones de veces la edad del universo.... (sí, lo he calculado :-))

Comment: @abulafia Si hay una pista y es que las letras mayúsculas y minúsculas se encriptan de la misma forma. Además el mensaje sí puede contener la ñ.

Comment: @abulafia me gustaría saber mas que todo como puedo pasar el texto cifrado a código binario de tal manera que pueda usar XOR.

Answer (score 10):

## Actualización. No era imposible

Al final no fue necesario esperar varias veces la edad del universo para romper el código. El mensaje descifrado comienza así:

```
'Bastará decir que soy Juan Pablo Castel, el'
```

(puedes poner más bytes del mensaje? Tengo curiosidad por saber como sigue)

La clave OTP necesaria para descifrarlo no te la voy a decir, pero te voy a contar el proceso que seguí para encontrarla. La idea clave es la siguiente:

> La clave sólo tiene 16 bytes, y el mensaje tiene muchos más.
>
> Esto implica que, una vez elegido el primer byte de la clave, ese primer byte decodificará todos los bytes del mensaje que estén en posiciones múltiplo de 16. **Y todos ellos** deben dar lugar a caracteres válidos. Y lo mismo con el siguiente byte que decodificará las letras en posiciones múltiplo de 16 más 1, etc.

Así pues podemos crear una lista de caracteres válidos, que contendría el alfabeto ASCII, más las vocales acentuadas, más los signos de puntuación, y probar todos los valores de 8 bits que pudieran genarar un carácter válido al hacer XOR con el primer byte del mensaje.

Esto es relativamente sencillo. Si queremos que la primera letra del mensaje sea la `A`, ya que el primer byte del mensaje era `f4` (244), haciendo `244^ord("A")` obtenemos 181. Por tanto usando como primer byte de la clave OTP 181, la primera letra del mensaje decodificado sería "A". Pero este mismo byte hay que aplicarlo a las letras en posiciones 16, 32, 48... y todas ellas deben producir como resultado un carácter válido. Si detectamos que no es así, podemos descartar 181 como primer byte de OTP (y la "A" como primera letra del mensaje).

Usando esta idea, es posible construir una lista que te diga todos los posibles valores que podría tomar el primer byte de OTP (y por tanto todos los posibles valores de la primera letra del mensaje) que no causen caracteres inválidos más adelante. Lo mismo para el byte siguiente, y así para los 16 bytes de la clave.

Este sería el código que hace este trabajo:

```
# Texto cifrado (hex)
data = "f4c4e842d8d77c7323770fa3520a954bd385e859c085d726267c4c9a4148885196e6fa45cdc0f17f677700"
# Separado como secuecia de byets
mensaje = [ int(data[i:i+2], 16) for i in range(0, len(data), 2) ]

# Conjunto de letras  que consideraremos válidas
letras_validas = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!(),.:;?@ áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚüÜñÑ'

# Variable para guardar el resultado buscado. Será una lista de listas
# El elemento i-ésimo de esta lista será otra lista con todos los posibles
# valores válidos para el byte i-ésimo de la clave OTP
result = []

# Para cada byte de la OTP buscada
for n in range(16):
  result.append([])
  # Generar todos los posibles valores de ese byte que genere caracteres válidos
  for c in sorted(letras_validas):
    codigo = c.encode("latin1")[0]
    cifra = codigo ^ mensaje[n]  # Esta cifra dará el carácter c (válido) al aplicarse a mensaje[n]
    # Aplicamos esa cifra a todos los bytes del mensaje en posición múltiplo de 16 + n
    descifrado = bytearray(cifra ^ mensaje[i] for i in range(n, len(mensaje), 16)).decode("latin1")

    # Y verificamos que el resultado está formado por letras válidas, no sólo para la que
    # estaba en posición n (esa ha sido generada de modo que lo sea), sino también para
    # todas las demás
    if all(letra in letras_validas for letra in descifrado):
      result[n].append((codigo, descifrado))
```

Con esto aún estamos lejos de haber hallado la solución, y encima a partir de aquí ya no se puede seguir de forma automática, sino que hace falta una persona (a ser posible aficionada a crucigramas y sopas de letras).

En `result[i]` tenemos posibles valores para el byte i-ésimo de la clave buscada. Por ejemplo `result[0]` muestra:

```
[(182, 'Be '),
 (183, 'Cd!'),
 (190, 'Jm('),
 (191, 'Kl)'),
 (184, 'Lk.'),
 (186, 'Ni,')]
```

Los números (182, 183, etc) son posibles valores del primer byte de OTP. Las cadenas que aparecen luego serían las letras que aparecerían en la posición 0, 16, 32, ... del mensaje usando ese byte como OTP.

Por ejemplo, si decido que el primer byte sea 182, la primera letra del mensaje sería una "B" y más adelante aparecería una "e" (en posición 16) y luego un espacio " " (en posición 32). Por tanto, con esta elección, el texto descifrado hasta el momento sería:

[image: primera letra]

Pero si hubiera elegido el código 183, la solución tentativa sería esta otra:

[image: Otra tentativa]

Es buena señal todas las posibles primeras letras sean mayúsculas, pero a priori no tenemos motivos para decidirnos por ninguno de esos casos.

Pero las posibilidades para la siguiente letra pueden ayudarnos a decidir. A fin de cuentas tenemos que ir formando palabras en español. Mi programa da que los siguientes posibles valores de códigos y letras para la siguiente posición serían (`result[1]`):

```
[(165, 'a C'),
 (172, 'h)J'),
 (173, 'i(K'),
 (169, 'm,O'),
 (171, 'o.M'),
 (190, 'z;X')]
```

Hay casos que podemos descartar, pues se trata de ver qué palabras se pueden ir formando con las opciones disponibles. Por ejemplo, no vamos a hacer aparecer dos consonantes seguidas, o una mayúscula despues de una minúscula...

Así que si elijo 182 para el primer byte de la OTP y 165 para el segundo, el descifrado hasta ahora iría así:

[image: Segundo byte]

que no tiene mala pinta, pues la `C` mayúscula que aparece al final va tras un espacio, por lo que podría tratarse de un nombre propio.

Tenemos hacia el medio una "e" y luego un espacio ¿podría tratarse de la palabra "de" o tal vez de "que"? Podemos consultar que letras hay posibles para la posición anterior (`result[15]`).

Salen gran cantidad de opciones (el texto suministrado por el usuario es muy corto, si hubiera sido más largo seguramente muchas de esas opciones habrían desaparecido, pues cuanto más largo es el texto mayor es la probabilidad de generar caracteres no válidos si usamos la cifra incorrecta). Pero podemos buscar entre ellas a ver si alguna tiene una "d" o una "u" como primer carácter. Vemos que ninguna tiene "d", pero sí hay una con "u":

```
# result[15] = 
[(107, ' :'),
 (106, '!;'),
 ...
 (62, 'uo'),
 ...
 (184, 'óé')]
```

Así que elijo la cifra 62 como último byte de la OTP y el texto descifrado de momento es:

[image: otra letra]

Y así proseguiría, en una especie de "juego del ahorcado", guiado por los valores posibles que me da `result`. A medida que van saliendo palabras reconocibles, es más fácil decidir cuál ha de ser la letra siguiente. ¡Así hasta resolverlo completo!

---

Lo que sigue es la respuesta original, que dejo aquí por el interés histórico.

---

## El enunciado es incompleto o el problema es imposible

Como mencioné en otros comentarios, no veo forma de resolver el ejercicio (es decir, de encontrar el texto sin cifrar) a menos que el enunciado esté incompleto, pues encuentro los siguientes problemas:

- La clave OTP es más corta que el texto. Cabe suponer que la misma clave se aplica cada 16 caracteres en el texto (16 bytes son 128 bits). No se trata por tanto de [One Time Pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad), pues en éste la clave ha de ser más larga que el texto. Aunque podría tratarse de [One Time Password](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_password)
- No existe algoritmo para descifrar el texto salvo la aplicación de *fuerza bruta*, es decir, probar una a una todas las claves de 128 bits posibles y para cada una aplicarla a los 16 primeros caracteres del texto y ver si el resultado "tiene sentido", en cuyo caso podríamos confiar en que aplicando la misma a grupos de 16 caracteres descifraríamos el texto completo. Los problemas de este enfoque son:

  - ¿Cómo saber si lo que sale "tiene sentido"? A fin de cuentas hacer xor de dos bytes siempre sale otro byte ¿con qué criterio decidimos si el byte resultante "podría ser" el correcto o no? La única pista es que el texto está en latin1, pero esto no es mucha pista, pues en ese *encoding* prácticamente cualquier resultado, salvo los que comienzan (en binario) por 0000, 0001, 1000 o 1001 podrían potencialmente ser correctos. Haría falta un "lector humano" que lea el resultado para reconocer si se está formando o no una palabra con sentido.
  - El número de combinaciones a probar es astronómico. Con 128 bits hay `2**128` combinaciones. Aún si descartamos algunas, como los 64 casos que corresponden a los patrones antes señalados, no ganamos gran cosa. Podemos bajar el número de casos a testear a `2**118` que sigue siendo monstruoso. Testeando a razón de mil millones de claves por segundo, el tiempo estimado para encontrar la correcta sería unas cuarenta mil millones de veces la edad el universo. Naturalmente puedes tener suerte y dar con la correcta al primer intento :-)

## Por donde empezar

Pese a todo, si quieres intentarlo (suerte!), en un comentario indicas que de momento te vale con saber cómo pasar la cadena hexadecimal a binario para hacer el XOR. Así que vamos con eso, que esto sí es asequible.

En realidad no necesitas pasar a binario la cadena. Basta que la conviertas a una secuencia de enteros, de tamaño byte, pues Python hace la operación lógica XOR a nivel de bits entre dos enteros, con el operador `^`. Por ejemplo:

```
a = 0x31
b = 0xf6
print(hex(a ^ b))       # Imprime 0xc7
print(hex(a ^ b ^ a))   # Imprime 0xf6
```

Por tanto basta separar tu cadena de dígitos hexadecimales en grupos de 2, y convertir cada grupo a entero (esto puede hacerlo `int(cadena, 16)`) para tener una lista de enteros:

```
data = "f4c4e842d8d77c7323770fa3520a954bd385e859c085d726267c4c9a4148885196e6fa45cdc0f17f677700"
enteros = [ int(data[i:i+2], 16) for i in range(0, len(data), 2) ]
```

Esto te dejará en `enteros` la lista `[244, 196, 232, 66, 216, 215, 124, 115, 35, 119, 15, 163, 82, 10, 149, 75, 211, 133, 232, 89, 192, 133, 215, 38, 38, 124, 76, 154, 65, 72, 136, 81, 150, 230, 250, 69, 205, 192, 241, 127, 103, 119, 0]`

Ahora podemos ir aplicando el XOR con una clave dada. Por ejemplo, probemos con la clave (generada al azar):

```
otp = "bbcf635ff7a9a668d8bbedd1e8b2f83d"
```

Lo primero será convertir esa clave también a una secuencia de enteros:

```
otp_enteros = [ int(otp[i:i+2], 16) for i in range(0, len(otp), 2) ]
```

Ahora podemos ir haciendo el XOR entre cada elemento de `enteros` con cada elemento de `otp_enteros`. Como no tienen la misma longitud, me limitaré a los primeros 16 bytes (`zip()` se detendrá cuando se termine la secuencia más corta de las que recibe como parámetro)

```
descifrado = [ a ^ b for a,b in zip(otp_enteros, enteros) ]
```

El código descifrado es una secuencia de enteros (en este caso ha salido `[79, 11, 139, 29, 47, 126, 218, 27, 251, 204, 226, 114, 186, 184, 109, 118]`) ¿cómo saber si es correcta? Podemos intentar convertirla en texto y mostrarla como latin1:

```
print(bytearray(descifrado).decode("latin1"))
```

Lo que produce:

```
O
 �/~Ú▒Ìârº¸mv
```

(icluido el salto de línea, que es en realidad un "Vertical Tab" correspondiente al ASCII 11). No tiene buena pinta. A seguir probando!

**Nota**. Si en lugar de sólo los primeros 16 caracteres quieres descifrar el texto completo, debes repetir los números en `otp_enteros` una y otra vez, hasta llegar al final del mensaje. La biblioteca `itertools` tiene un método `cycle()` precisamente para esto. Lo usarías así:

```
descifrado = [ a ^ b for a,b in zip(itertools.cycle(otp_enteros), enteros) ]
```

Comment: Parece que el texto es parte de [El tunel, de Ernesto Sábato](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/375603-bastar-decir-que-soy-juan-pablo-castel-el-pintor-que) con lo que puedo saber cómo sigue sin tener más bytes del mensaje :-)